# Context Menu in Word Add Ins

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I am developing an Add In for Microsoft Word. I am looking to Add Customised Context Menus . Is it feasible to have context Menu in Word documents?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can. You need to use add-in commands, who enable you to not only add right-click context menus, but also buttons up in the ribbon. You need to add some annotations in the add-in manifest. There is quite a lot of detailed documentation  on how to do it here: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/add-in-commands